# Rotate the player in XNA

Tags: c#, rotation, xna, game-physics

I've been looking around for a tutorial on how to do this properly and Google keeps coming up empty. Maybe this is a really simple subject, but I'm not sure what to do.

What I've found so far gives me code that looks like this:

```
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            RotationAngle += 0.01f;
            float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
            RotationAngle = RotationAngle % circle;
        }
```

Only, this doesn't do much. It came from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb203869%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx). That was the best-looking solution I could find.

All I want to do is allow the player to spin their ship around and shoot in another direction.
I'm making a game that bears a fair resemblance to asteroids, but I can only shoot in one direction at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: This is my current Player.cs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace GameTest
{
    class Player
    {
        public Texture2D PlayerTexture;
        public Vector2 Position;
        public bool Alive;
        public int Health;
        public Vector2 origin;
        public float RotationAngle;
        KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
        KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;
        public int Width
        {
            get { return PlayerTexture.Width; }
        }
        public int Height
        {
            get { return PlayerTexture.Height; }
        }


        public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
        {
            PlayerTexture = texture;

            Position = position;

            Alive = true;

            Health = 10;

            origin.X = PlayerTexture.Width / 2;
            origin.Y = PlayerTexture.Height / 2;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            RotationAngle += 10f;

            previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;
            currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

            float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {

                //float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
                //RotationAngle = RotationAngle % circle;
            }

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                //rotation
            }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerTexture, Position, null, Color.White, RotationAngle, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using that `RotationAngle` when drawing your sprite to screen? I'm fairly certain the `SpriteBatch` has overloads that may or may not require a rotation.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do much"? Is the player drawn rotated? Do you now need to work out how to shoot at an angle for example?

Comment: I am using it in the `SpriteBatch`, yeah. And I mean it doesn't rotate the sprite at all, it does nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are missing the 'origin', or the center of rotation:

```
RotationAngle += .5f;
float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
RotationAngle = RotationAngle % circle;

Vector2 origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texure.Height / 2);

spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, RotationAngle, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

As for the angle you want to shoot at, you'll need some geometry (something like this, not tested... but if I remember correctly):

```
Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(speed*Math.Cos(RotationAngle), speed*Math.Sin(RotationAngle));
```

Also, use the debugger to make sure that the rotation angle is properly changing.

Comment: I just noticed and stuck that in the code.. but all that did was shift the position of the laser origin for some reason

Comment: I changed the `RotationAngle` to just 30f and it rotated the ship perfectly fine. I've no idea what's stopping the code from rotating the ship..

Comment: Hmm... Try changing the rotation angle in the main update method, so it updates on every call (without needing a button press I mean), and tell me what happens.

Comment: Nothing happens still. Does it make any difference that the code I'm editing is in a separate class? I have this code running in my Player.cs, but it should be all properly linked up to the Game1.cs file. In the `Draw()` method in Game1.cs, it calls `player.Draw(spriteBatch);` to draw the player.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, no... Try adding a bigger value to it (instead of .01).

Comment: I didn't think so.. At the moment, the top of the `Update()` method looks like this: 
`public void Update(GameTime gameTime) {RotationAngle += 10f;}`
But it's still not shifting the player..

Comment: Add your player class to your code if you could... As far as I can tell it should be working. You should follow your code with the debugger... when it hits draw, check the value of the rotation angle and what not.

Comment: Checked the debugger for any changes in the `RotationAngle` but no dice.

Comment: No dice as in.. it is changing or it isn't?

Comment: Are you remembering to call player.Update()?

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH. That would have had me confused for an awful long time.. That did it.